# Can't get "Test Mail Server Tool" working on Windows 8.1

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm trying to test the php mail() function on localhost so I installed [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/) but I can't get it to work.

I installed it, ran it, didn't change any settings. I then opened a php file in chrome that only contained the mail function, but no file was created in the "Mail Sent To Local Server" directory.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

PHP:

```
<? mail("foo@bar.com", "mail function test", "testtesttesttesttest"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to edit these two lines in php.ini

```
SMTP = 127.0.0.1
smtp_port = 25
```

And restart Apache

Comment: Alright, I see, one of the wamp php.ini files had a different value for SMTP. Working now.

Comment: What do you do if this doesn't fix it? I still get NO response of any kind even after making sure these values are correct (and restarting the server).